# Is there an absolute value sign missing here? Factoring a term out of a square root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\int_{1}^{8}\frac{x^2}{27x^2/8}\sqrt{1+x^{-2/3}}dx=\frac{8}{27}\int_{1}^{8}x^{-1/3}\sqrt{1+x^{2/3}}dx$$

Shouldn't $x^{-1/3}$ be $|x^{-1/3}|$ because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$?

Comment: It doesn't matter since $x$ is between $1$ and $8$.  However if the integral were from $-1$ to $-8$ you would need a minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

Converting to an answer: Since $ x \in [1, 8] $, it does not matter.